# Looking for JavaScript taggable input text plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not even sure if Stack Overflow is a good place to ask for plugins. If not, I will gracefully receive downvote waterfall.

What I need is client-side solution, perhaps jQuery/Bootstrap or just pure JS plugin, to make my input text taggable. But I need it to not just accept tags, but also accept normal text.

My inputs should accept tags in `{tag}` format. As I type opening curly brace, it would suggest all possible tags, for example:

```
{name}
{title}
{category}
{age}
```

If I type tag or select it, it would be highlighted in my input, but this is optional. The most important thing is to be able to see all possible tags when I open curly brace and being able to select them. The purpose of this input field is to type values such as:

> My cousin {name} is {age} years old.

Now, I don't ask how to do it, because I am able to do it myself. The question is if there's already existing solution to this time consuming problem, as it will likely be better than my own.

Comment: you can do everthing you want using jquery ui

Comment: Yeah :) You will most likely receive waterfall downvote.
May I recommend you using:
https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/

Comment: well you can use angularjs then.

Comment: Why would you use curly brackets, just [search Google](https://www.google.rs/search?q=jquery+tag+input&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr&ei=x7JnV5S3M4XuUL_Ik4gH) and find one plugin you like.

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

- http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/
- http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Twitter-Like-Mentions-Auto-Suggesting-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Suggest/
- http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-An-Tweet-Like-Text-Box-with-jQuery-Tweetbox/

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question :) Second plugin suits my need best out of 3, but still doesn't quite fit. I need to be able to put text immediately after tags too, that's why it's a little different than mentions funcionality. It's very close though!